# Zapier - Dropbox + Gmail issues

Tags: gmail, dropbox, zapier

I'm trying to connect dropbox and gmail together.

Actually it's working, when a new file appear in a specific folder on dropbox I receive an email with the attachment.

But, the problem for each folder I have on dropbox I've to make a specific zap...

I've got 30 folders and only 20 zaps with my starter plan... So I would like to have ONE and ONLY zap for all my folders

We recommended me to use the webhook.

Your help is welcome guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear to me but it seems you'd need to use the new Zapier path feature. That way, you'll create one zap with multiple paths. You'll have to set the condition for each path and the zap will run for the path that matches your condition.